# SQL Query searching for a string of keywords and finding optimal results

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the most efficient and elegant mysqli query when searching 1 column for a string of multiple keywords to produce optimal results that have the most keywords from that string? Just like a google search engine.

For example, the string is "fuji raw apples without skin"

First the query would look for the exact string (fuji raw apples without skin)
Second it looks for that string in a different order (apples without skin fuji raw)
Third shows results that have some of the words, but not all (raw fuji apples)

I'm basically trying to make an optimal search engine that finds the closest results to the keyword string the user enters.

Comment: Fulltext index, elastic search .......

Comment: Check out the documentation here on what MySQL can do with full text searching.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html  Note this is the documentation for the latest version, 8.0.